# Accessing properties of @input target object with component

Tags: angular

This component:

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input()
  child: Child;

  mychild: Child = { 
    id: this.child.id,
    name: this.child.name: 
  };
}
```

returns this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.child.id')
```

Aren't the properties of the @Input target object automatically available within the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mychild` property is assigned in component constructor. The bindings aren't available at this point.

[Lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) exist to make this possible. According to the reference,

> ngOnInit
>
> Initialize the directive/component after Angular initializes the
>   data-bound input properties.
>
> ngOnChanges
>
> Respond after Angular sets a data-bound input property. The method
>   receives a changes object of current and previous values.

And the order of execution is

> ngOnChanges
>
> before ngOnInit and when a data-bound input property value changes.
>
> ngOnInit
>
> after the first ngOnChanges.

So it should be

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  child: Child;

  mychild: Child;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mychild = { 
      id: this.child.id,
      name: this.child.name: 
    };
  }
}
```

if `child` input isn't supposed to be changed after initialization, otherwise `ngOnChanges` hook should be used.

The code above seems to be redundant, because `this.child` is already available after initialization and can be used directly instead of `this.mychild`.